# tar backup zsh script

Tags: linux, backup, shell-script, zsh, tar

Trying to set up a cronjob ran tar script to backup site (without .git and setup folder) every night and upload time stamped archive to Dropbox.

It gives me a hard time as archive is created along with everything in it, seems exclude flag doesn't work for some reason now. Maybe it's the zsh's character escape the issue, not sure, still learning. Please help..

```
#!/bin/zsh

DATE=`date +%d-%m-%Y---%H-%M-%S`
FILE=backup-$DATE.tar.bz2
DROPBOX=/home/pentago/appz/bin/dropbox.py 
TARGET=/home/pentago/public_html/
DESTINATION=/home/pentago/Dropbox/Backups
EXCLUDED={setup,.git*}


tar -cpPf $FILE --exclude=$EXCLUDED $TARGET{*,.*}
```

Answer (score 2):

There a re a few problems in your script. You need to add the `j` option to `tar` in order to create bzip2 files. I believe the exclude commands are ignored because you are explicitly adding *all* files in your target to tar's imput file list. You don't need `$TARGET/*` simply `$TARGET` will do. Finally, the excluded blob is probably being expanded in your current directory, not in the target directory.

Try something like this:

```
#!/bin/zsh

DATE=`date +%d-%m-%Y---%H-%M-%S`
FILE=backup-$DATE.tar.bz2
DROPBOX=/home/pentago/appz/bin/dropbox.py 
TARGET=/home/pentago/public_html/
DESTINATION=/home/pentago/Dropbox/Backups



tar -cjpPf $FILE --exclude=setup --exclude=.git $TARGET
```

Comment: nah, it still doesn't exclude .git and setup directories from archive.. :/

Comment: @purpler The real problem is probably that `EXCLUDED={setup,.git*}` doesn't expand properly.

Comment: @slhck wow, great timing, I just figured that out :). Any way to avoid hard coding the excludes?

Comment: @purpler it should work now.

Comment: Not from my head, no. Have to look up how the brace expansion works, maybe it needs to be `eval`d first? For safety reasons I'd suggest to quote the variables properly. Even if they don't include whitespace, it's probably a good habit to develop.

Comment: Actually, in the OP's original solution, `$TARGET/*` would have skipped `.git` anyway since the `dotglob` option is turned off by default and therefore doesn't match hidden files.

Comment: @terdon: I'm not sure waht you mean by "hardcoding the excludes". A possibility resembling the OP's workflow is: `EXCLUDED=(setup ".git*") ... tar --exclude=$EXCLUDED`. You need the `RC_EXPAND_PARAM` option set; anyway it's always a good idea for scripts to start with `zsh -f` (to be independent of any (user's) zshrc files) and then explicitly set the non-defaults options inside the script.

Comment: @mpy I mean being able to pass the excludes list as an option rather than hard coding it into the script.

Answer (score 0):

You really should be using git-archive for that.

```
git archive -o $FILE HEAD
```

to avoid including `setup` you'll need to set the attribute `export-ignore` on it. See `man gitattributes` and `man git-archive` (loads of examples). Notice that that assumes that setup is checked-in, if not you don't have to do anything.

Comment: ok man but i didn't ask for help with git, rather backup shell script.

Comment: Since you were excluding .git dir, I just assumed you were backing up a git repo.

Comment: No, i was trying to backup my shell account files daily to Dropbox, disregard git..